# Extending play body parsing

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

We are building a play app in Java. We are using play 2.1.

I'm stuck at how can I extend play to parse body based on the url query parameter instead of content-type header and return the result as JavaObject.

I think it can be done by writing a custom BodyPraser but there are 2 problems with that approach

1. I've to do in Scala and that would eat up more time as I don't know Scala.
2. I don't want to write a BodyParser per se. A small logic before parsing that checks the content type and uses Play api to parse the content.

After parsing the body, I'd like to deserialize the content to a JavaObject. Something like this..
RequestBody.as(UserDTO.class)

This will decouple the controller code from the representation that could be either in XML, JSON etc.

So, what is the best way I can do this in play?